# C# NullReferenceException unhandled (with string array)

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
string[] buttons = new  buttons[5];
int j = 0;
while (j<5)

    {
       buttons[j] = pullString(node);
       j++;
    }
```

However I get a NullReferenceException unhandled error pointing to the first line of the code inside the while block. Please explain!

Comment: Copy and paste your code, please. This won't even compile.

Comment: I somehow doubt you actually have `string[] buttons = new buttons[5];`

Comment: Why are you using a while loop and incrementing a variable?  Wouldn't it make more sense to just use a regular for loop?

Comment: Post the code for `pullString()`

Comment: I dumbed it down quite a bit for this example. the pullString works in other code. I think it's bc I haven't instantiated a string or something in the string array.

Comment: @Zack: No, strings act similar to value types. Either `node` is null or you have a flaw in your logic in `pullString`

Comment: @Zack, when you "dumb it down," be sure you *dumb it down to something that compiles and still exhibits the problem.* It's useless to get dumb it down past the point of anyone being able to assist you.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that the `pullString` method is throwing this exception. And because you haven't shown the body of this method in your question, that's the best answer you could get so far. Not to mention that the following line:

```
string[] buttons = new  buttons[5];
```

would require some tweaking on the C# compiler in order to compile (unless of course you have defined an alias to the string type: `using buttons = System.String;` which I heavily doubt about).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this should be

```
string[] buttons = new string[5];
```

the `NullReferenceException` is thrown by `pullString(node)`, everything else is fine.